# Plot with thumbnails that open other plots

Tags: pdf

How can I make the following kind of plot? On a "master" plot, say a US map, if you click on map locations a smaller "slave" plot opens up, say state population vs. time. Prefer to implement this as a PDF but other formats OK. Already have map and state population plots (jpg, bmp, or eps); just need architecture of clicking & opening the slave plots.

Comment: If PDF allows HTML type imagemaps that link to other (bookmarked) locations in the document then that should do what you want.

Comment: This makes it sound possible, http://www.planetpdf.com/developer/article.asp?ContentID=Image+Mapping+in+PDF+-+Create+a+JavaScript+Color+Picker